# JS: Compare and validate two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to arrays:

```
const values = [
  {
    id: "c22d8560-2d42-45c0-9ca0-91a4eabd193d",
    capacity: 8
  },
  {
    id: "be63bd14-f448-4dc4-8087-3b895095d0bc",
    capacity: 6
  },
 {
    id: "djkfu4-xvvxvx-4344-sddsd",
    capacity: 1
  }
]



const allowedValues = [
  {
    id: "c22d8560-2d42-45c0-9ca0-91a4eabd193d",
    capacity: 3
  },
  {
    id: "be63bd14-f448-4dc4-8087-3b895095d0bc",
    capacity: 2
  }
]
```

I need to check if capacity from exact object from `values` exceeds the one from `allowedValues` and return an error.

So, based on example, the expected response is:

```
[
  { 'c22d8560-2d42-45c0-9ca0-91a4eabd193d': 'Allowed capacity is 3' },
  { 'be63bd14-f448-4dc4-8087-3b895095d0bc': 'Allowed capacity is 2' },
];
```

Is it possible to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

### Code

```js
const response = values
    .map((value) => {
        const allowedValue = allowedValues.find((allowedValue) => {
            return allowedValue.id === value.id;
        }) ?? { capacity: Infinity };
        return {
            ...value,
            allowedCapacity: allowedValue.capacity,
        };
    })
    .filter((value) => {
        return value.capacity > value.allowedCapacity;
    })
    .map((value) => {
        return {
            [value.id]: `Allowed capacity is ${value.allowedCapacity}`,
        };
    });
```

### Explanation

Map the values to a list of objects that look like `{id, capacity, allowedCapacity}` and use `Infinity` for entries that don't have an allowed capacity. Then filter that to only the results where the capacity exceeds the max allowed capacity. Then map that result into the desired format where the keys are `id`s and the values are error messages containing the max capacity.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward and descriptive means of accomplishing this is to create a lookup table out of the `allowedValues` array, and then reduce the data array against that.

Here using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the lookup, and a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop to process the result.

```js
const values = [ { id: 'c22d8560-2d42-45c0-9ca0-91a4eabd193d', capacity: 8, }, { id: 'be63bd14-f448-4dc4-8087-3b895095d0bc', capacity: 6, }, { id: 'djkfu4-xvvxvx-4344-sddsd', capacity: 1, }, ]; 
const allowedValues = [ { id: 'c22d8560-2d42-45c0-9ca0-91a4eabd193d', capacity: 3, }, { id: 'be63bd14-f448-4dc4-8087-3b895095d0bc', capacity: 2, }, ];

const avMap = new Map(allowedValues.map(({ id, capacity }) => [id, capacity]));

const result = [];
for (const { id, capacity } of values) {
  if (avMap.has(id) && capacity > avMap.get(id)) {
    result.push({ [id]: `Allowed capacity is ${avMap.get(id)}` });
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can easily achieve the result by first creating a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) if `id` and `capacity`

const dict = new Map(allowedValues.map(({ id, capacity }) => [id, capacity]));

**2)** Loop over `values` array using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to mach the `id` and get the result

```js
const values = [
  {
    id: "c22d8560-2d42-45c0-9ca0-91a4eabd193d",
    capacity: 8,
  },
  {
    id: "be63bd14-f448-4dc4-8087-3b895095d0bc",
    capacity: 6,
  },
  {
    id: "djkfu4-xvvxvx-4344-sddsd",
    capacity: 1,
  },
];

const allowedValues = [
  {
    id: "c22d8560-2d42-45c0-9ca0-91a4eabd193d",
    capacity: 3,
  },
  {
    id: "be63bd14-f448-4dc4-8087-3b895095d0bc",
    capacity: 2,
  },
];

const dict = new Map(allowedValues.map(({ id, capacity }) => [id, capacity]));

const result = values.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (dict.has(c.id) && c.capacity > dict.get(c.id))
    a.push({ [c.id]: `Allowed capacity is ${dict.get(c.id)}` });
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```